# How to fill the missing values of a column with the mean of a specific class of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I share a part of my big dataframe here to ask my question. In the *Age* column there are two missing values that are the first two rows. The way I intend to fill them is based on the following steps:

1. Calculte the mean of age for each group. (Assume the mean value of Age in Group A is *X*)
2. Iterate through Age column to detect the null values (which belong to the first two rows)
3. Return the *Group value* of each Age null value (which is 'A')
4. Fill those null values of Age with the mean age value of their corresponding group (The first two rows belong to A then fill their Age null values with *X*)

I know how to do step 1, I can use `data.groupby('Group')['Age'].mean()` but don't know how to proceed to the end of step 4.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: can you post your data as text please? just copy and paste it as is into a code block

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['Age'] = (df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby('Group')['Age'].transform('mean'))
                      .astype(int))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also, how do I use the round result of the mean as in integer because the calculated mean is a fraction number?

Comment: you can do .astype('int32') at the end

Comment: you are welcome, I think you can use `.astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this:

```
df['Age'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Age'].transform(lambda x: np.where(np.isnan(x), x.mean(),x))
```

Assuming your data looks like this (I didn't copy the whole dataframe)

```
    Name    Age
0   a   NaN
1   a   NaN
2   b   15.0
3   d   50.0
4   d   45.0
5   a   8.0
6   a   7.0
7   a   8.0
```

you would run:

```
df['Age'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Age'].transform(lambda x: np.where(np.isnan(x), x.mean(),x))
```

and get:

```
    Name    Age
0   a   7.666667   ---> The mean of group 'a'
1   a   7.666667
2   b   15.000000
3   d   50.000000
4   d   45.000000
5   a   8.000000
6   a   7.000000
7   a   8.000000
```